# Port linear Game to Unity

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am programming the table top game "Get Bit!". First i created a console version and now I'm trying to port it to Unity.

My Problem:

In console the whole game is linear. So PlayCards() asks the Player what card he wants to play and then waits until user enters its value.

In unity I'm trying to get the input via Buttons, but that does not wait for user Input and contues with MoveSwimmer() and so on. I tried to get the value via while(inupt == -1), but that freezes the whole game.
Currently the Run() method is in a class Game : MonoBehaviour attached to camera.

Here's the code of the problematic functions *after taking McAden's advice*:

```
void Game::Update ()
{
    this.GameRun = true;
    Debug.Log(string.Format("Round: {0}", (round - 1)));
    Debug.Log("POSITION: " + PlayerPositionString());

    while (GameRun)
    {
        PlayCards();
        MoveSwimmers();
        GetBit();
        EndTurn();
    }

    Debug.Log(string.Format("Congrats! Player {0} won!", playerPosition.First()));
}

private void Game::PlayCards()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < playerScripts.Count; i++)
    {
        if (playerScripts [i].IsAlive())
            cardsPlayed.Add(playerScripts [i].PlaceCard());
    }
}

override public Card Player::PlaceCard()
{
    // a MonoBehaviour that shows for each card a Button that sets the value member ChoosenCardValue (on default -1).
    GUICardChooser chooser = Camera.main.GetComponent<GUICardChooser>();

    while (chooser.ChoosenCardValue == -1)
        ;

    int cardIndex = cards.FindIndex(c => c.Value == chooser.ChoosenCardValue);
    Card theChoosenOne = cards [cardIndex];
    cards.RemoveAt(cardIndex);

    return theChoosenOne;
}
```

Am I focussing on the wrong pattern? How can I fix this issue?

Thanks for help.

Comment: it's quite ridiculous this question was not closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity3D you don't need to define your own game loop. Unity [already does that for you](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html). Create an `Update` function.

Inside your `Update` function - check for input and react to it. Since it's in a loop, use `if` instead of while. `Update` is already within a loop though you might end up looking up the differences between it and `FixedUpdate`.

something like:

```
void Update
{
  if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.LeftArrow))
  {
    DoSomething();
  }
}
```

You'll want to research the [different ways of dealing with input](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Input.html). You won't always want to use `GetKeyUp`. You might use `GetAxis` or `GetButtonUp` for example.

As [@Didier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3511252/didier) suggests in his answer you'll probably want to end up implementing a State Machine of some sort in the long run.

Comment: I didnt wanted to use the Update loop, because it does not wait for the user to play a card. How do I make the Update function to wait until the user played a card? (Maybe thats related to my user input)?

I just added the PlaceCard() in my post - I think that's the real reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: That's the reason for the State Machine. You'd do the Place Card in its own state, or in a transition.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should look through Unity docs and Unity samples.

But if you want to implement it one of the possibilities would be to create a state mashine. And inside your Update() method you will behave according to your current state. But it's just one possibility. It all depends on your gameplay...